# pythonic way of finding a value in a list which hasn't been supplied

Tags: python, list

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
a = 0
b = 1

c = range(3)
```

so I would like to find the missing number in the list which in this case would be 2.

The way I have programmed it at the moment is cumbersome and ugly.

If there was a function opposite to list.append() so that I could remove values from the list instead that would be great to.

Thanks

Comment: So, you just have a bunch of variables that your checking the existence of the values within your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [set difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html) by converting the list to a set, then preforming the set difference operation.

```
>>> supplied_list = [0, 1]
>>> list(set(range(3)) - set(supplied_list))
[2]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [sets](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html):

```
>>> a = 0
>>> b = 1
>>> c = range(3)
>>> set(c) - set([a, b])
set([2])
```

Answer (score 1):

[`list.remove`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq) will remove the first occurrence of a given value from a list.  If you want to specifically remove the last item (the one that was appended), use `list.pop`.